# How to change for loop with an array module function?

Tags: arrays, f#

This is a school assignment. I'm trying to make a function which takes an array A and makes a new array B, which is telling how many repeated numbers there are in an array. For example A is this:

A = [|2;9;9;2;2;4|]

The B would be:

B = [|3;2;2;3;3;1|]

Ny code is right now like this and working perfectly:

```
let A = [|2;9;9;2;2;4|]
let n = A.Length - 1

let B = Array.create A.Length 0
for i = 0 to n do 
    Array.iter (fun j -> if i <> j && A.[i]=j then B.[i] <- (B.[i] + 1)) A

printfn "%A" B
```

My question is, how much would asymptotic time be? I know the first for loop is O(n), but what about Array.iter? And is there any way to switch the first for loop with an array function?

Comment: `Array.iter` is also linear

Comment: So the overall time Will be O(n^2)?

Comment: Yep, that's correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Array.iter` is linear in the array length, so your for loop is essentially O(n²) in time complexity. Replacing the loop with another `Array.iter` is possible but would not change the time complexity.

If you can solve the problem whichever way you want, I suggest using a Map to aggregate the numbers and their frequencies, then mapping the original array into one showing these frequencies. Since this is a school assignment, you should probably wait until after your submission deadline before you look at the following code:

```
let numFrequency (a : _ []) =
    let m =
        (Map.empty, a)
        ||> Array.fold (fun m n ->
            Map.tryFind n m
            |> Option.defaultValue 0
            |> fun x -> Map.add n (x + 1) m)
    Array.map (fun n -> Map.find n m) a

let A = [|2; 9; 9; 2; 2; 4|]

let B = numFrequency A

printf "%A\n%A\n" A B
```

Comment: Thank you for that! So just to be clear, the time complexity of the code above will be linear then or still O(n^2)?  (I'm new to time complexitys, so I'm not really sure what time complexitys array functions have)

Comment: Not sure about the time complexity of ``Map.find``/``Map.tryFind`` but if I'm not mistaken, it's O(log n). With ``Array.fold`` and ``Array.map`` showing a time complexity of O(n), that makes a total time complexity of O(n log n) for the algorithm.

Comment: Thank you for that!  :)